# Can't access a folder on my Windows SMB share

Tags: smb

I've been sharing a folder I have on my Windows 10 PC, which has many movies. The idea is to be able to watch them on my TV.

Until now, I had no issues with sharing. I bought a new portable hard drive which I have transferred all movies into. After sharing the new folder, I came across this issue where it asks me for credentials (which I provide but do not give me access). I have another folder placed on another drive which is shared as well, but I can access it normally as before.

So, to conclude, I connect to my SMB share, see 2 main shared folders. One of which I can access and the other one asks me for credentials or loading indefinitely. I tried playing with sharing permissions and copying the other folder's one to the new one, but nothing seem to work. Do you guys have any idea on a fix? Or maybe I can provide you with some log (if so, please tell me how, I have no much knowledge on SMB shares).

Comment: You will need to determine which user(s) have ownership of the file and more then likely share the file with everyone.

Comment: I already do that. I give ownership to my own account, and share with everyone.

Comment: If you have shared with everyone then it shouldn't be asking you to authenticate, since you have an anonymous share configured, which means everyone has read/write access.  So did you try to reconfigure the sharing?

Comment: I did. Actually now it's not listing anything when I connect.. Just indefinite loading.

Comment: Have you tried to restart the machine the device is connected to?

Comment: Yes, I have restarted and now able to connect to the folder I was able to connect to in the first place. Though, the folder I'm trying to fix is still inaccessible. Do you want me to post screenshots of my sharing permissions and security permissions?